# Nested Insert and Select statement

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO [log].[BatchEvent](BatchId, SeverityId, Date, Message) VALUES((SELECT [Id] 
FROM [log].[Batch] WHERE [EndDate] IS NULL), @SeverityId, @Date, @Message)
```

This is the query that I am trying to execute. But the problem is it works only if one `ID` is returned from `Batch` table.

How do I insert multiple rows into `BatchEvent` if multiple id's are returned from `Batch`?

Comment: I don't see any `c#` here

Comment: Foreach Id returned make the thing you were doing when only one was return. And by the way you should read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you to find a way to structure your thought when asking question. that alone will solve 90% of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use insert select without the `values` keyword. You can return the other values as 'fake' column from the select, because the select needs to have the same number of columns as specified in the insert clause:

```
INSERT INTO [log].[BatchEvent](BatchId, SeverityId, Date, Message) 
SELECT [Id], @SeverityId, @Date, @Message FROM [log].[Batch] WHERE [EndDate] IS NULL
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks :D

Comment: You're welcome. :-) Make sure to read "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)".